# Can SQLite3 be upgraded on Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, sqlite3

I would like to upgrade SQLite3 on my Ubuntu instance that is running version 3.8.2.  The current release is 3.11.1.x.  I wanted to know if there is any risk in doing so since SQLite3 is a core tool to Ubuntu and many apps use it.

If its safe to do, what is the best approach?  Install from the Linux distribution or download source and build?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid nobody can possibly tell you that it is safe. That would mean that we can be 100% sure that the changes made after 3.8.2 will not affect your installation. That is obviously impossible. The prudent way would be to test the new version on a test system that is not used for production, and if nothing goes wrong as far as you can see, upgrading your production system.

It might be wise to read the [release notes](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) though.

Answer (score 1):

If everything works fine for you on 3.8.2 I advise you to not upgrade. Take a look to the [change-log](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) to see if any change important to you has been done.

---

SQLite 3.8.2 is the latest stable and supported version for Ubuntu 14.04.

SQLite 3.11.1 is the package aimed at Ubuntu 15.04 and is currently only present in the Vivid Vervet repository.

Refer [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sqlite3) for more information.

---

If you still want to upgrade :

On Ubuntu 15.04 you simply need to run the following command to update your SQLite package :

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

On Ubuntu 14.04 you have to download and install [Precompiled Binaries for Linux](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) available on SQLite website.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that any major changes would be made in a minor release change from 3.8.2 - 3.8.11.

If SQLite uses [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) like many projects do, the only time major changes that would affect compatibility are made is between major versions (eg. 3.x.x -> 4.x.x in this case).  Thus, you *should* be okay to upgrade it, but of course you should read over the [changelogs](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) for confirmation.

As for the proper way to do it, if you keep your system up to date, then you will have the most up to date version of SQLite3 available to your Ubuntu release available in the official repositories. You can make sure of this by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

As it stands currently, the newest version of SQLite3 available to 14.04 LTS is 3.8.2, as per [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sqlite3). The latest version available through official repositories *period* is the 3.8.11.1 release, available to the 15.10 release.

Thus, if you want to use 3.11.x on your system, you will have to do it manually from sources provided by SQlite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can

Just follow instructions at the last lines in this dockerfile https://github.com/disarticulate/docker-python-sqlite and fresh libsqlite3.so will be installed to /usr/lib

Then discover actual placement of system wide libsqlite3.so (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, for ex) and correct symlinks to be pointed to /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so been compiled earlier